# Upvoting off-topic questions of new users to allow entry to chat

Tags: discussion, voting, new-users

It occurred to me earlier today that there are quite a few new users who come here with various questions that are considered off-topic per MY's guidelines. Often, these first questions are closed and these users seem to disappear. Now, it takes a minimal amount of reputation to allow entry into MY's main chat , V'dibarta Bam (20 points, שהם two upvotes la'omer), and these questions more often than not don't receive upvotes, and usually even some downvotes. Thus, these new users looking for info can't use the chat.

Out of interest of perhaps assisting people (or chesed, or something similar), what are your thoughts on upvoting such questions to allow these new users to use the chat, then directing their questions over to there, where they may yet receive assistance?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't advise gaming the vote system for that purpose. Votes are supposed to be based on content, not to reward (or punish or give chat access to) the content's author.

If I'm not mistaken, a Mi Yodeya moderator can, if needed, grant explicit access to someone with too-low rep to chat in a specific room.

Comment: Can confirm that it works, I've done it in the past

Comment: Thanks, @Mithical